# WARNING Circular dependency detected - Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

So I have composite an Angular application having internal projects and their sub-modules under the parent module. I am able to export and share the children's components with the parent using their modules.

However, I am unable to share the parent components with the children. Anytime I configure the modules, I get the error; `circular dependency`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by factoring out the circular dependency into a separate module.

> For instance, if module A imports foo from module B, and module B imports bar from module A, it is enough to extract foo into module C.

So I created an external shared module, declaring all shared components and defining exported components, and then importing them in the child modules.

[This](https://%20youtube.com/watch?v=p2Bvtv5PUJ0) tutorial vid helped me understand it better.

I hope this helps. :)